# C# Dataset usage necessary before passing to GridView datasource?

Tags: c#, gridview, dataset

#### Scenario

Lets say for example I have a series of events that fire continually every half second presenting me with an object containing some bits of information. There are always between 10 and 15 objects that are being updated constantly. Since these bits of information are changing continually I want to display them in a GridView. When I do so, I want the user to see the data displayed in the gridview and actually be updated as opposed to just a continually extending list being printed and incrementing (like writeline on the console).

#### Question

Is the best way to achieve this to map my objects to a dataset and have the dataset mapped to the gridview?

#### Thoughts

Will this allow the gridview to just be "UPDATED" as opposed to being added to?

Any implementation suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

#### EDIT:

it MUST be windows forms (I use DevExpress too)

Comment: I'd suggest that you look at using the data binding of WPF (and perhaps a MVVM pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the DataSet for something else than the GridView? Fo GridView you can use a BindingList<T> it is better for displayint objects in grid-like controls.